# How to set content type of Upload blob to storage container action in Azure Logic App

Tags: containers, storage, action, azure-logic-apps, service-accounts

I am using action "upload blob to storage container" of logic app to create blob to convert base64 to pdf in azure logic app workflow,
but unable to set the content type in this action ,
can someone please suggest how to set the content type of this action.

I tried to use this through update flag available with this action like "Content-Type=application/pdf" but it is giving  error ,I want to set content type to application/pdf.

[image]

Comment: I don't see an `upload blob to storage container` operation.  There's a `Create blob (V2)` which allows you to adjust the content-type so can you please show us your flow?

Comment: If you search for -  "Upload blob to storage Container " in chose an operation option, then you get this action .

Comment: Show your flow. Without it, we can’t help you because of right now, what you’re wanting to do is easy and I can’t confirm that until I see your flow.

Comment: Sorry , as I have not enough reputation points I am unable to upload the image of my workflow, have share the link of that image . hope it is useful to you.

Comment: It looks like you're using LogicApps standard, is that right?

Comment: yes using logic app standard

Comment: Ok, that’s the difference.

Answer (score 2):

In **upload blob to storage container** there is no direct way to set content type. An alternative approach is using create blob action. I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I have done,

1. Created logic app as shown below,

[image]

2. I have a base64 file stored in blob storage and getting the content using Get blob content(V2) action.
   [image]
3. The content of base 64 file is ,

```
bmFtZSxhZ2UsaWQsc2VydmljZQ0KdmlqYXlhLDIwLDExMixsb2dpY2FwcHMNCnN1YmJ1LDIxLDIxMSxhZGYNCmxhdGhhLDE5LDExMyxmdW5jdGlvbnMNCmFzaCwyMiwxMTQsd2ViYXBwcw0K
```

4. In create blob action decoding content of file using function **base64ToString()** and setting content-type as **application/pdf**
   [image]
5. Once logic app run, file is uploaded into blob storage.
   [image]
   Uploaded file in storage,
   [image]

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer , yeah I can do the same thing with Create Blob(v2) but it is an Azure connector so that it is creating Api connection by default while I interested in creating Service provider connection which is created by default with Upload blob to storage connector.

Comment: Any another connector  in which by default service provider connection will create and which perform the same thing please suggest.

Comment: As of now create blob action is not available in logic apps built in connector

Comment: Content-Type parameter is not visible by default and I had to add it via 'Add new parameter' dropdown

Comment: Yes you need to add it in add new parameter